# jQuery XML parse with multiple instances of same tag within parent tag

Tags: jquery, xml, xml-parsing

Trying to get specific tag from an XML message that looks like:

```
<Output>
 <Name>FirstName</Name>
 <value>FirstValue<value/>
 <Name>SecondName</Name>
 <value>SecondValue</value>
</Output>
```

What I'm looking to do is to get the value of the second  tag.  If I do something like result = $(XML).find("value").text(); it lumps them together like FirstValueSecondValue.  I've tried using .Children() and .filter() as well but to no avail.

Just a note.  I unfortuntlely have to get this working in 1.4.2 (I know, so outdated).

I appreciate any help anyone can offer.

Answer (score 1):

An answer in case anyone stumbles across this question in a search:

```
$(xml).find("value").eq(1).each(function(){
   console.log($(this).text());
});
```

For more information: http://api.jquery.com/eq/

Answer (score 0):

```
$(xml).find('Output').each(function(){    

    $values=$(this).find("value");
        $.each($values, function() {
          alert($(this).text()) ;
          });

)};
```

This will work,